# How to handle session time out warning with JQuery and ColdFusion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, coldfusion, session-timeout

I currently have JS function that handles session timeout in my Single Page App. On first try seemed to be the best solution that I have. Simply this function will be triggered on page load and send Ajax call to the server to keep session alive. Then I have found better solution for this purpose. ColdFusion has `onRequestStart()` function that will be triggered every time user reloads the page or send request to the server. I have set the time flag in that function. Here is example:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
     <cfargument name="thePage" type="string" required="true">
     <cfset REQUEST.appName = 'Single Page Application'>
     <cfset REQUEST.lastHit = now()>
     <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

On my home `.cfm` page I have used `toScript()` to convert lastHit to JS. Here is example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">  
     <cfoutput>
         var #toScript(REQUEST.lastHit, "lastHit")#  
     </cfoutput>
     // Check last hit on every request
     var getLastHitTime = new Date(lastHit).getTime();
</script>
```

I'm wondering how I can start calculating 30 minutes from that lastHit time stamp? This way this function will refresh every time user makes request to the server. If they don't make hit to the server for 28 minutes give them a warning and start counting 120 seconds down. I'm wondering what would be the easier way to accomplish this? I saw JQuery has some plugin but not sure how to use it or if that plugin is reliable. Using onRequestStart lastHit scope value I would prevent sending Ajax request to the server since I have time stamp with the most recent interaction between the user and the server. If anyone can provide some suggestions or examples please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: hmm... Wouldn't it be simpler to just return a different status code to ajax requests that aren't logged in, then if  you have a session id client-side you know it timed out, or if you don't have a session id you know the user wasn't logged in. If you rely on a timestamp, that's going to easily break if the session is ended for any other reason.

Comment: @KevinB Let say user is typing some real long form and takes some break and comes back then keeps typing so no request is being sent to the server for 29 minutes. Once server counts 30 minutes user would be kicked out without any warning and lose all their data. In my opinion I should give them a warning 2 minutes before session expires. If they click ok to continue then I send ping to the server.

Comment: You would want to routinely check the current time with some kind of interval, but keep in mind that intervals in inactive tabs don't fire the same way they do in active tabs. I'd suggest instead somehow saving the user's information in localstorage if this is a common occurrence.

Comment: @KevinB Is there any good example of how to handle session time out in JQuery or JS?

Comment: We use javascript timers for this sort of thing.  Depending on the actual page, we will either allow their login to die and display words to that effect, or, in the case of time consuming data entry pages, do something to keep them logged on.  Allowing the login to die is the default behaviour.

Comment: If it's a one-page site, can't you start the JS timer on page load? Using `setTimeout()` you can fire off any function after 25 minutes. But if you're simply looking to keep the session alive - use `setInterval()` to create a bogus ajax request to a blank CFM file, every 25 minutes. If any of these makes sense for your use, I can post a full example as the answer.

Comment: @Jules if you can provide some example that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-page site, you can start a JS timer on page load to display a warning:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('You are about to lose unsaved changes. Please post the form.');
}, 25 * 60 * 1000); // 25 minutes
</script>
```

If you want to keep the session alive indefinitely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var keepAlive = setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        'type': "GET",
        'url': "/includes/blank.cfm?rand="+ Math.random(),
        'success': function (data) {
            tmp = data;
        }
    });
}, 25 * 60 * 1000); // 25 minutes
</script>
```

Just be sure to point to a real CFM, even if it's a blank file.

Comment: Thanks for providing example. Is there a reason why you have to use Math.random() as parameter in your ajax call?

Comment: GET is cached. You want to make sure the request hits the server. The random url var helps with that. You can POST instead, but GET has better performance.